# geonetwork editor-- labels for fields defined in a template

Tags: geonetwork

I'm customizing the geonetwork editor for ISO19115-3 and want to only show some of the fields for temporal extent, so I'm defining a template only field :

```
 <field name="temporalExtentName" xpath="/mdb:MD_Metadata/mdb:identificationInfo/mri:MD_DataIdentification/mri:extent/gex:EX_Extent/gex:temporalElement"
            templateModeOnly="true">
            <template>
              <values>
                <key label="beginName"  xpath="gex:EX_TemporalExtent/gex:extent/gml:TimePeriod/gml:begin/gml:TimeInstant/gml:name"/>
                <key label="endName"      xpath="gex:EX_TemporalExtent/gex:extent/gml:TimePeriod/gml:end/gml:TimeInstant/gml:name"
                />
              </values>
              <snippet>
                <gex:temporalElement>
                  <gex:EX_TemporalExtent>
                    <gex:extent>
                      <gml:TimePeriod>
                        <gml:begin>
                          <gml:TimeInstant>
                            <gml:name>{{beginName}}</gml:name>
                          </gml:TimeInstant>
                        </gml:begin>
                        <gml:end>
                          <gml:TimeInstant>
                            <gml:name>{{endName}}</gml:name>
                          </gml:TimeInstant>
                        </gml:end>
                      </gml:TimePeriod>
                    </gex:extent>
                  </gex:EX_TemporalExtent>
                </gex:temporalElement>
              </snippet>
            </template>
          </field>
```

Currently it just shows the string for the field name, and the two fields under that are blank boxes.

I want to label the fields for the two variables in the form-- is there some way to do that?